# Different width of UIDatePicker iPhone and iPad in iOS 7

Tags: ios7, uidatepicker

I'm working on conversion of a universal app for iOS 7. I found difference in behaviour of UIDatePicker in iPad and iPhone.Code is same for both the devices but It's not showing full screen width in iPhone. However in iPad Date picker width is fullscreen. Please help me. Thanks

[image: iPad Screenshot]

[image: iPhone Screenshot]

Comment: I also got same issue with my iPhone app. Please post if you find any solution.